# Which recursive calls are allowed in Haskell array creation?

Tags: haskell, recursion

As a short exercise in using Haskell arrays I wanted to implement a function giving the first n (odd) prime numbers. The code below (compiled with GHC 7.10.3) produces a loop error at runtime. "A Gentle Introduction to Haskell" uses recursive calls in array creation to compute Fibonacci numbers (https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/arrays.html, 13.2, code below for reference), which works just fine. My question is:

Where is the difference between the two ways of recursive creation? Which recursive calls are generally allowed when creating arrays?

My code:

```
import Data.Array.Unboxed

main = putStrLn $ show $ (primes 500)!500 --arbitrary example


primes :: Int -> UArray Int Int
primes n = a
  where
    a = array (1,n) $ primelist 1 [3,5..]
    primelist i (m:ms) =
      if   all (not . divides m) [ a!j | j <- [1..(i-1)]]
      then (i ,m) : primelist (succ i) ms
      else primelist i ms
    divides m k = m `mod` k == 0
```

Code from "A Gentle Introduction to Haskell":

```
fibs    :: Int -> Array Int Int
fibs n  =  a  where a = array (0,n) ([(0, 1), (1, 1)] ++ 
                                     [(i, a!(i-2) + a!(i-1)) | i <- [2..n]])
```

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I think I finally understood what's going on. `array` is lazy on the list elements, but is unnecessarily *strict* on its spine!

This causes a `<<loop>>` exception, for instance

```
test :: Array Int Int
test = array (1,2) ((1,1) : if test!1 == 1 then [(2,2)] else [(2,100)])
```

unlike

```
test :: Array Int Int
test = array (1,2) ((1,1) : [(2, if test!1 == 1 then 2 else 100)])
```

So, recursion works as long as it only affects the values.

A working version:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   putStrLn $ show $ (primes 500)!500 --arbitrary example

-- A spine-lazy version of array
-- Assumes the list carries indices lo..hi
arraySpineLazy :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, a)] -> Array Int a
arraySpineLazy (lo,hi) xs = array (lo,hi) $ go lo xs
   where
   go i _ | i > hi = []
   go i ~((_,e):ys) = (i, e) : go (succ i) ys

primes :: Int -> Array Int Int
primes n = a
  where
    a :: Array Int Int
    a = arraySpineLazy (1,n) $ primelist 1 (2: [3,5..])
    primelist :: Int -> [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
    primelist i _ | i > n = []
    primelist _ [] = [] -- remove warnings
    primelist i (m:ms) =
      if all (not . divides m) [ a!j | j <- [1..(i-1)]]
      then (i ,m) : primelist (succ i) ms
      else primelist i ms
    divides m k = m `mod` k == 0
```

Arguably, we should instead write a lazier variant of `listArray` instead, since our `array` variant discard the first components of the pair.

---

This is a strictness issue: you can't generate *unboxed* arrays recursively, only boxed (regular) ones, since only boxed ones have a lazy semantics.

Forget arrays, and consider the following recursive pair definition

```
let (x,y) = (0,x)
```

This defines `x=0 ; y=0`, recursively. However, for the recursion to work, it is necessary that the pair is lazy. Otherwise, it generates an infinite recursion, much as the following would do:

```
let p = case p of (x,y) -> (0,x)
```

Above, `p` evaluates itself before it can expose the `(,)` pair constructor, so an infinite loop arises. By comparison,

```
let p = (0, case p of (x,y) -> x)
```

would work, since `p` produces the `(,)` before calling itself. Note however that this relies on the constructor `(,)` not evaluating the components before returning -- it has to be lazy, and return immediately leaving the components to be evaluated later.

Operationally, a pair is constructed having inside tho *thunks*: two pointers to code, which will evaluate the result later on. Hence the pair is not really a pair of integers, but a pair of indirections-to-integer. This is called "boxing", and is needed to achieve laziness, even if it carries a little computational cost.

By definition, unboxed data structures, like unboxed arrays, avoid boxing, so they are strict, not lazy, and they can not support the same recursion approaches.

Comment: Since the Fibonacci example works, this means that Array has the right lazyness properties. Then the problem should be fixed if I replace UArray by Array in my code sample (and import Data.Array). Unfortunately, the modified code still produces a loop error at runtime.

Comment: @sf1 See my last edit. It was much more subtle than I thought.